# how to check matroid condition in greedy

Tags: algorithm, greedy

I am reading about matroids at following link.

https://www.cse.buffalo.edu/~hungngo/classes/2004/531/notes/matroids.pdf

After reading several times I am not getting to answer following question

Example of a matroid
 M1 = (S1; I1) where S1 = {1,; 2; 3 } and I1 = {{1,2},{2, 3}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {empty}}

Example of a non-matroid

M2 = (S2; I2) where S2 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5,} and

I2 = {{1,2 3}; {3, 4, 5} {1,2} {1,3} {2,3} {3,4}, {4,5}, {1}, {2},{3}, {4}, {5}, {empty}}

Why isn't M2 a matroid?

My question is why M1 is matroid and M2 is not matroid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition tells us, that the following should apply:

```
Hereditary: B ∈ I and A ⊆ B imply A ∈ I.
```

Let's have a look at I2:

- take B as {3,4,5}
- then take A = {3,5} -> A ⊆ B valid
- BUT the following is not valid, but needs to be: {3,5} ∈ I

**EDIT**: You miscopied the original matroids -> the upper counter-example is only valid for your post, not for the link!

**Counter-example for the link:**
The following need to be valid:

```
Exchange property: if A ∈ I and B ∈ I and |A| < |B|, then ∃x ∈ B − A so that A ∪ {x} ∈ I.

- take A = {5}, B = {1,2} -> A ∈ I, B ∈ I, |A| < |B|
- then: B-A = {1,2} -> BUT:
  A = {5} ∪ {1} NOT ∈ I
  A = {5} ∪ {2} NOT ∈ I
  -> implication invalid!
```